# delete old Locations in iOS App Google Maps

Tags: ios

I have several former locations in the App but nowhere as far as I know is there an option to delete the location; indeed it has multiplied: I once used it to get to local offices of the Social Security Administration & it has multiplied to several other offices in the neighborhood of SSA.gov

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).